# Why my Borderlands is not integrating correctly with Steam?

Tags: steam, borderlands

I bought Borderlands GOTY pack on Steam, but I already had it downloaded (piracy, yarn).

I uninstalled the game and imported it on steam using this method:

1. Install the game to the hard drive from the installation disc.
2. Once that's done, tell Steam to install the game, but pause the download as soon as it starts.
3. Find the directory that Steam's installing to, and copy all the files from the install you made in step 1 to the Steam install directory. (If there's an uninstall executable or install log file you don't need to copy it over.)
4. Restart the download in Steam. It will now only download files that are either missing or changed. (Steamworks files or updates, mainly)
5. When it gets near the end, I've found it occasionally stalls... (As Lobsang stated, usually at 99%...) If this doesn't happen, skip ahead to step 5. If this DOES happen, follow these steps...

   5.1. Create a temp folder on the same hard drive as your steam installation.

   5.2. Make sure Steam is still downloading the game (Doesn't matter if it's suspended...) and move all files from the Steam installation folder to the Temp folder you created in Step 4.1

   5.3. Now if you go back to the Steam installation folder, you'll see a few files are still there. These are the files that are causing Steam to stall...

   5.4. Close Steam And delete the offending files from The Steam Folder AND from the Temp directory you moved everything to.

   5.5. Move everything back from the temp directory to the Steam Installation directory

   5.6. Restart Steam, and Steam should now download the files it was stuck on from scratch.

   5.7. If it should get stuck again, (Personally I've never had this happen, but it could theoretically happen, follow steps 4.1 - 4.6 again... If the download completes, Head on to step 5...
6. Once the download completes, Go to your Games List, right click on the Game list, and Select Properties. Click on the Local Files Tab and click on 'Verify Integrity Of Game Cache'
7. Once that's all done, your game should now be fully installed in Steam...

Steam already checked the game cache, and it was OK.

The problem is that SHIFT TAB is not working and my achievements are not "popping" on screen  once I achieve them, even tho they are working correctly.

Any idea of why they are not appearing on my in game screen once I achieve them?

Comment: So, in short, your Steam UI overlay isn't working?  Does it work with any other games?

Comment: Yes, the steam ui integration is working with every other game but borderlands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably your copy has some method of circumventing Steamworks that persists even when you attempt to download changed files from Steam. Backup your saves (located in "C:\Users\Your Username\Documents\My Games\Borderlands\SaveData" for Windows 7/Vista and somewhere similar for XP) and remove Borderlands entirely. Ignore step one and step three, simply let Steam install the game. This should restore full Steam compatibility.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps the install media you downloaded does not feature a true Steam compatible version of the game. Follow the same steps of removing and reinstalling exclusively from Steam to fix.

Comment: I was avoiding having to download the game entirely since 12GB is alot to download. But this will probably solve my issue, you are right, the copy i downloaded probably had no steamworks compatibility.
Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, i already reinstalled from scratch borderlands using steam, and it is still not working properly with the steamworks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your old shortcut, and not launching through steam?  If so right click on the game in the steam window and select create new shortcut.

Steam launches the app a different way to include the overlay.

Comment: I am using the shortcut on steam